# Adding fields of case classes in scala

Tags: java, scala, types, pattern-matching, field

I have the following case classes. Expressions are boxed mathematical operations and numbers. For example add is a subclass of expression and it recursively contains two fields that are num, which is subclass of expression as well.

```
  abstract class Expression
  case class num (num: Int) extends Expression
  case class add  (left: Expression, right: Expression) extends Expression

  abstract class Result
  case class numericResult (v : Int) extends Result
```

There are other types of Return as well so I can't remove case classes

Evaluate method is supposed to take expression, unbox it then perform the operation and return a result that is boxes in Result class

```
def evaluate(expr: Expression ) : Result = {
    expr match {
      case num(n) => new numericResult(n)
      case add(l, r) => new numericResult(evaluate(l).v + evaluate(r).v) //add will never be called on imaginary numbers
      case addi(l, r) => new imaginaryResult(...)  //adds imaginary numbers

    }
}
```

But when I try to evaluate it, I get an error:

```
error: value v is not a member of Result
```

How can I make sure Scala knows that l and r are of type num and when evaluated will give numericResult rather than Result? I can assume that in case add evaluate(l) and evaluate(r) will return numericResut, but l and r might me be nested adds as well.

Comment: Why don't you then return `numericResult` from `evaluate`?

Comment: def evaluate (expr: Expression) :numericResult = ...

Comment: There are other types that evaluate can return

Comment: Then update the question: ..so I can assume evaluate(l) will always produce numericResult.. -- this contradicts with your last comment

Comment: I also have imaginaryResult, which returns imaginary numbers and some others

Comment: Then you can't assume evaluate(l) will always produce numericResult :)

Comment: Would: `new numericResult(evaluate(l).asInstanceOf[numericResult].v + evaluate(r).asInstanceOf[numericResult].v)` be acceptable?

Comment: @PawełJurczenko will blow if `evaluate(l)` returns `imaginaryResult`

Comment: Assuming that only for add case. asInstanceOf will work, but it ruins the purpose of static types system in scala. I was looking for a cleaner solution (possibly it does not exist)

Comment: @AlexSmirnov pattern matching is just a syntactic sugar of `instanceOf`, no magic here

Comment: @AlexSmirnov if there are expressions that can evaluate either as `integer` or `imaginary`, make it explicit in Expression subtypes

Answer (score 1):

Parameterize the `Expression`s by the type of `Result` that they produce:

```
abstract class Expression[T <: Result]
case class num (num: Int) extends Expression[numericResult]
case class add  (left: Expression[numericResult], right: Expression[numericResult]) extends Expression[numericResult]
case class addi (left: Expression[Result], right: Expression[Result]) extends Expression[imaginaryResult]

abstract class Result
// why lower-case? 
case class numericResult (v : Int) extends Result
case class imaginaryResult(v: Int) extends Result

def evaluate [T <: Result](expr: Expression[T] ) : T = {
  expr match {
    case num(n) => new numericResult(n)
    case add(l, r) => new numericResult(evaluate(l).v + evaluate(r).v) //add will never be called on imaginary numbers
    case addi(l, r) => new imaginaryResult(???)  //adds imaginary numbers
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the variant that validates your evaluation result in runtime:

```
def evaluate(expr: Expression ) : Result = {
    expr match {
      case num(n) => new numericResult(n)
      case add(l, r) => (evaluate(l), evaluate(r)) match {
           case (numericResult(l), numericResult(r)) => new numericResult(l + r)
           case (x, y) => throw new IllegalStateException(s"Numeric Results expected, got $x, $y")
      }
      case addi(l, r) => new imaginaryResult(...)  //adds imaginary numbers
    }
}
```

However, in order to get type safety in compile time, you need to consider complimenting `Expression` type with [dependent types](http://wheaties.github.io/Presentations/Scala-Dep-Types/dependent-types.html), say, expected result type of evaluation.